# Link to Like a specific comment on facebook?

Tags: html, facebook, hyperlink, facebook-like

I've been looking around for a way to link to a specific comment so that when people click the comment will be "Liked" 
All the info I have about the comment is:

button class="stat_elem as_link cmnt_like_link" type="submit" name="like_comment_id[5822057]" value="5822057" title="Like this comment"

Can anyone tell me how to link a like button to that specific comment with id 5822057 ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the documentation on comments and graph api [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Comment/), but basically it says this:

> You can like a comment by issuing an HTTP POST request to
>   COMMENT_ID/likes with the publish_stream permission. No parameters
>   necessary.

so the link for you would be

> http://graph.facebook.com/5822057/likes?access_token=[YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]&method=post

This should set you on the right path.

Comment: I can't figure it out. I need to have people be able to like a comment I made but they seem to have to like the page where I posted it first and then they can search for my comment and then like it. Is there an easier way?